# Spring-Boot: How can I build a runnable jar with SBT?

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot, sbt, sbt-assembly

How can I build a runnable jar with SBT?
Perhaps Spring-Boot isn't suitable for SBT built applications? Any suggestions on this?

I tried using sbt-assembly but it fails when I try to run it.
Note that `sbt run` works

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.xagongroup.xagon.app.XagonETL")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.x.app.XETL]; nested exception is java.lang.Ille
galArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.x.app.XETL$.main(XETL.scala:21)
        at com.x.app.XETL.main(XETL.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:277)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what build tool you use, as long as the resulting JAR is compliant with the format described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar. Have you checked that?

Comment: @dunni Okay- I looked into the .jar and it doesn't look compliant at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: Change your build script, so that it creates the JAR like it should be. I don't know SBT, so i can't help you further here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving to sbt-native-packager

#### *plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0")
```

#### *build.sbt*

```
scriptClasspath := Seq("*")
mainClass in Compile := Some("com.x.app.XETL")
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

### Running:

1. packaging
   `sbt universal:stage`
2. starting the app:
   `target\universal\stage\bin\x.bat`

Comment: Thanks this worked! :-) would be nice to have the incantation to allow sbt-assembly to do it right too. Thanks again

Comment: Hi it works, but I have other problem. If I run simple spring application I set application properties in runtime using `java -jar -Dproperty.name=value file.jar`. How can I do that using `target/universal/stage/bin/executable-file`?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this without any plugins. It seems the only trick here is to **not** discard META-INF/spring.factories files in your build.sbt

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
   case PathList("META-INF", "spring.factories") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
   case PathList("META-INF", _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
   case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still is not enough because spring boot has special fat jar format that allows packaging libraries into the main jar (somewhat akin war files), and assembly cannot do it

Answer (score 0):

In order to save someone else's time:

### Brief

Spring Boot uses special [jar format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) which has different inner structure, changes to manifest and can contain jars inside, which should be just stored in resulting archives as-is (it is called `ZipEntry.STORED` in contrast with `ZipEntry.DEFLATED`).

### Solution

Neither of plugins I knew (sbt-assembly or sbt-native-packager) could do it from the box or with configuration, so I just wrote a custom task for this which can package my relatively simple project (no modules and subprojects).

#### File layout

```
...usual build folders...
project/
    SpringBootJar.scala
build.sbt
```

#### build.sbt

Note the addition of **spring-boot-loader** in the dependencies and **springBootJar** task.

```
import SpringBootJar.Keys.springBootJar
import SpringBootJar.springBootJarTask

val springBootVersion = "2.7.6"

lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
     name := "my-project",
     scalaVersion := "3.2.1",
     ...
     
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-parent" % springBootVersion pomOnly(),
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-jdbc" % springBootVersion,
       .... other depenencies ....
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-loader" % springBootVersion % "compile"
    ),
    springBootJar := springBootJarTask.value
)
```

#### SpringBootJar.scala

```
import sbt.{Keys, _}
import Keys._
import sbt.io.Using.fileOutputStream
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.util.jar.{Attributes, JarEntry, JarFile, JarOutputStream, Manifest}
import java.util.zip.{CRC32, ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet

object SpringBootJar {
  object Keys {
    val springBootJar = taskKey[Unit]("Create spring boot fat jar")
  }


  val springBootJarTask = Def.task {
    val log = streams.value.log

    // check if spring-boot-loader is already a dependency
    libraryDependencies.value.find(_.name == "spring-boot-loader") match {
      case Some(_) => log.info("spring-boot-loader: present")
      case None => sys.error(s"Consider added spring-boot-loader to libraryDependencies")
    }

    // name of resulting artifact
    val destArtifact = target.value / s"${name.value}-${version.value}-sb.jar"

    val classpath = (Runtime / fullClasspath).value
    val externalClasspath = (Runtime / externalDependencyClasspath).value
    val classDir = (Compile / classDirectory).value
    val resourceDir = (Compile / resourceDirectory).value

    // create directory structure
    val rootDir = IO.createUniqueDirectory(target.value)
    val springBootLoaderDir = rootDir / "org" / "springframework" / "boot" / "loader"
    val appClassesDir = rootDir / "BOOT-INF" / "classes"
    val libsDir = rootDir / "BOOT-INF" / "lib"

    // get the location of the spring-boot-loader library on the file system
    log.info("Seeking for spring-boot-loader jar")
    val springBootLoaderFile = classpath.find(_.data.getName.startsWith("spring-boot-loader")) match {
      case Some(af) => af.data
      case None => sys.error("Couldn't find spring-boot-loader, interrupting")
    }

    // create dir structure
    log.info("Creating directory structure")
    IO.createDirectories(Seq(springBootLoaderDir, appClassesDir, libsDir))

    // creating manifest
    log.info("Creating MANIFEST")
    val manifest = new Manifest()
    val mainAttributes = manifest.getMainAttributes
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0")
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.SPECIFICATION_TITLE, name.value)
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.SPECIFICATION_VERSION, version.value)
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.SPECIFICATION_VENDOR, organization.value)
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_TITLE, name.value)
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION, version.value)
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VENDOR, organization.value)
    mainAttributes.put(new Attributes.Name("Start-Class"), (Compile / mainClass).value.getOrElse(""))
    mainAttributes.put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher")

    // copy all from org/springframework/boot/loader/ to the same path
    locally {
      log.info("Copying org/springframework/boot/loader/ classes")
      val jar = new JarFile(springBootLoaderFile)
      val entries = jar.entries()
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        val entry = entries.nextElement()
        if (!entry.isDirectory && entry.getName.startsWith("org/springframework/boot/loader/")) {
          val targetPath = entry.getName.stripPrefix("org/springframework/boot/loader/")
          val targetFile = new File(springBootLoaderDir, targetPath)
          targetFile.getParentFile.mkdirs()
          Files.copy(jar.getInputStream(entry), targetFile.toPath)
        }
      }
      jar.close()
    }

    // copying all own app files
    log.info("Copying app classes")
    IO.copyDirectory(classDir, appClassesDir)

    // copying app resources
    log.info("Copying app resources")
    IO.copyDirectory(resourceDir, appClassesDir)

    // copying all external libs
    log.info("Copying libs")
    IO.copy(externalClasspath.filterNot(_.data.base.startsWith("spring-boot-loader")).map {
      f => f.data -> libsDir / f.data.getName
    })

    // creating jar
    log.info("Creating jar")
    jar(
      (rootDir ** "*").get.map { file => (file, file.relativeTo(rootDir).get.getPath) },
      destArtifact,
      manifest,
      Some(System.currentTimeMillis())
    )

    log.info("Cleaning up")
    IO.delete(rootDir)

    log.info(s"Created: ${destArtifact.getAbsolutePath}")
  }


  private def jar(sources: Traversable[(File, String)], outputJar: File, manifest: Manifest, time: Option[Long]): Unit = {
    val localTime = time.map(t => t - java.util.TimeZone.getDefault.getOffset(t))
    if (outputJar.isDirectory)
      sys.error("Specified output file " + outputJar + " is a directory")
    else {
      val outputDir = outputJar.getParentFile match {
        case null => new File(".")
        case parentFile => parentFile
      }
      IO.createDirectory(outputDir)

      val emptyCRC = new CRC32().getValue // The CRC32 for an empty value, needed to store directories in zip files

      withJarOutput(outputJar, manifest, localTime) { output =>
        writeZip(sources.toSeq, output, localTime) { (file, name) =>
          val entry = new JarEntry(name)
          if (file == null || file.isDirectory) {
            entry.setSize(0)
            entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED)
            entry.setCrc(emptyCRC)
          } else if (file.ext == "jar") {
            val jarBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath)
            entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED)
            entry.setSize(jarBytes.length)
            entry.setCompressedSize(jarBytes.length)
            entry.setCrc({
              val crc = new CRC32()
              crc.update(jarBytes)
              crc.getValue
            })
          }

          entry
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private def withJarOutput(file: File, manifest: Manifest, time: Option[Long])(f: ZipOutputStream => Unit) = {
    fileOutputStream(false)(file) { fileOut =>
      val zipOut = {
        val os = new JarOutputStream(fileOut)
        val e = new ZipEntry(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME)
        e.setTime(time.getOrElse(System.currentTimeMillis))
        os.putNextEntry(e)
        manifest.write(new BufferedOutputStream(os))
        os.closeEntry()

        os
      }

      try
        f(zipOut)
      finally
        zipOut.close()
    }
  }


  private def writeZip(sources: Seq[(File, String)], output: ZipOutputStream, time: Option[Long])(
    createEntry: (File, String) => ZipEntry
  ): Unit = {
    val files = sources.flatMap {
        case (file, name) => if (file.isFile) (file, normalizeToSlash(name)) :: Nil else Nil
      }.sortBy {
        case (_, name) => name
      }

    val now = System.currentTimeMillis

    def addDirectoryEntry(file: File, name: String): Unit = {
      output.putNextEntry {
        val e = createEntry(file, name)
        e.setTime(time.getOrElse(now))
        e
      }
      output.closeEntry()
    }

    def addFileEntry(file: File, name: String): Unit = {
      output.putNextEntry {
        val e = createEntry(file, name)
        e.setTime(time.getOrElse(IO.getModifiedTimeOrZero(file)))
        e
      }
      IO.transfer(file, output)
      output.closeEntry()
    }

    // Calculate directories and add them to the generated Zip
    allDirectoryPaths(files).foreach(addDirectoryEntry(null, _))

    // Add all files to the generated Zip
    files foreach { case (file, name) => addFileEntry(file, name) }
  }


  private def normalizeToSlash(name: String): String = {
    val sep = java.io.File.separatorChar
    if (sep == '/') name else name.replace(sep, '/')
  }

  private def relativeComponents(path: String): List[String] =
    path.split("/").toList.dropRight(1)

  private def directories(path: List[String]): List[String] =
    path.foldLeft(List(""))((e, l) => (e.head + l + "/") :: e)

  private def directoryPaths(path: String): List[String] =
    directories(relativeComponents(path)).filter(_.length > 1)

  private def allDirectoryPaths(files: Iterable[(File, String)]) =
    TreeSet[String]() ++ (files flatMap { case (_, name) => directoryPaths(name) })
}
```

#### Usage

`sbt springBootJar` or `springBootJar` in sbt console.

### Conclusion

This was tested with scala 3.2.1 in project and sbt 1.7.1. I don't have time to make it into a plugin, and I don't mind if anyone reuse my findings to make more general and ready to use solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn't say it is GPT answer. I just used it as I would use google, which I also used along with sources of spring-boot, sbt & sbt-maven-plugin. The answer is not generated by GPT, this is the result of my 24 hr long struggle.